# How to calculate variant of geometric series based on sequences of Catalan numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, catalan-numbers

I want to calculate

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}k^{n+1}C$$

where $0<k<1$ and $C$ and $k$ are some constants, and $0<C$.
Is there any possible range of $0<C$ that allows easy calculation of this?

In general, how do I solve this sum?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#First_proof

Comment: As each large Catalan number is almost $4$ times the previous one, you may need something like $k\lt\frac14$ for convergence

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Differentiate with regard to the parameter *k*, and identify the [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) behind the new expression.